# How to make a Visual C# program restart itself

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I made a game in Visual C#.  It starts out with a welcome screen.  After the game ends, it says "game over."  Then I want the program to restart at the welcome screen like it was just started.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

call Application.Restart();

Comment: @Benny: Never thought of that *slaps head*....damn that was short simple and sweet...look at my post!!!! :) Nice one!

Comment: Won't that cause an infinite loop?

Comment: No, because my game has an exit button.

Comment: lol, that's not gonna help much if you call restart upon click.

Answer (score 4):

```
public void RunMyGame()
{
    bool isFinish = false;
    while (!isFinish)
    {
        ShowWelcome();
        InitVars();
        PlayTheGame();
        // We reach here when the game is finished
        // Play again? 'Y' isFinish set to false then loop
        isFinish = PromptToPlayAgain();
    }
}
```

Does this help?

Answer (score 2):

Is this a serious question? Since you are coding in C#, have you looked at that language's syntax for loops? Things like `while` or `for`?

If neither works out for you, check out the [GOTO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13940fs2.aspx) statement - it is awesome (I know that - I used it a lot in my first Commodore C-64 programs back in 1985)! Just ignore the community content at the bottom of the MSDN page that the link above takes you to - the first person obviously does not know what he (or she) is talking about.

Answer (score 1):

create a method to reset all variables and call the method used to start the game/display the start screen